# Clearing cache in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, caching, symfony5

How to clear cache in Symfony 5?

Official docs at https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#clearing-the-cache says that we should use the `php bin/console cache:pool:clear cache.global_clearer` command. However this does not clear cache because I was stuck for 20 minutes thinking why some files aren't refreshed.

Then I went with old way using `php bin/console cache:clear --env prod` however this breaks permissions all the time and I have to run `sudo chmod 777 -R var/cache` each time.

I am on Centos7.

Comment: Are you sure you are using proper file permissions? I would assume that the user clearing the cache does not have the same permissions than the webserver

Comment: This two commands do completely different jobs. `cache:clear` clears framework's cached files in **var/dev** or **var/prod** directory. but `cache:pool:clear`  clears data cached data that developer cached in redis, files system, database or ... depend on adapter she/he used.

Answer (score 0):

Is the user you use to clear the cache is the same as the php user ?

Your `chmod 777` works because of the last `7`. This is not a best practice.

Here is an exemple with Apache & PHP-FPM :

```
[php-fpm@myserver myproject]$ ll var/cache/prod/
total 756
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www   5688  2 déc.  15:33 annotations.map
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www 529129  2 déc.  15:33 annotations.php
drwxrwx---   2 php-fpm www   4096  2 déc.  15:33 ContainerEKUR7PE
drwxrwx---   3 php-fpm www   4096  2 déc.  15:33 doctrine
drwxrwx---  11 php-fpm www   4096  2 déc.  15:33 pools
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www    100  2 déc.  15:33 serialization.php
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www    761  2 déc.  15:33 srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www      0  2 déc.  15:33 srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php.lock
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www 103727  2 déc.  15:33 srcApp_KernelProdContainer.php.meta
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www  34142  2 déc.  15:33 srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php
drwxrwx---   2 php-fpm www   4096  2 déc.  15:33 translations
drwxrwx--- 114 php-fpm www   4096  2 déc.  15:33 twig
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www  12520  2 déc.  15:33 UrlGenerator.php
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www   5438  2 déc.  15:33 UrlGenerator.php.meta
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www  14979  2 déc.  15:33 UrlMatcher.php
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www   5438  2 déc.  15:33 UrlMatcher.php.meta
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www   5968  2 déc.  15:33 validation.php
-rw-rw----   1 php-fpm www   3240  2 déc.  15:33 webpack_encore.cache.php
```

Here is my umask :

```
[php-fpm@myserver myproject]$ umask
0007
```

And here is my user groups :

```
[php-fpm@myserver myproject]$ id
uid=996(php-fpm) gid=1000(www) groupes=1000(www),994(php-fpm)
```

My server is a CentOS 7 too.